# For-of loop in node --harmony doesn't work with arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

When I start node v0.11.14 REPL with `--harmony` option and try for-of loop, I get:

```
> for (var i of [3, 4, 5]) console.log(i);
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The same for sets. But it works fine with generators:

```
> function* Counter() { var n=3; while (n < 7) { yield n++; } }
> var c = new Counter();
> for (var i of c) console.log(i);
3
4
5
6
```

Though the first example from [ecmascript wiki page](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:iterators) is:

```
for (word of ["one", "two", "three"]) {
    alert(word);
}
```

[MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [Traceur docs](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/LanguageFeatures#iterators-and-for-of) contain the same example. I've failed to google "for-of in nodejs". Should it actually work in Node or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for .. of` and iterable objects were implemented separately in v8. It looks like in v8 bundled with node 0.11.14 you can use it only with generators.

You can check `obj[Symbol.iterator]` property to see if object is iterable, it should be a function. In my node build with v8 3.29.93 everything works as expected. So, you probably have to wait for the next 0.11 release (or 0.12).